# Variable in onDestroy to distinguich whether the app is being closed or the user changes the activity

Tags: android

I am trying  to remove the locationManger of my TrackingService class when the app is being closed and not when the user switches the activity

Is there anyway to distinguish between the both cases when the `onDestroy()` is being called?

I have a trackingService `locationManager`  component which processes in the background and it is launched from the `MainActivity` activity. At the same time, I have another component to retrieve this data from the server and displaying it in the `Map` activity. The user can access this data in the server from the MainActivity, when he clicks a buton in the MainActivity, then the alarmManager with the InsentService class starts retrieving data from the server to display it in the Map activity.

I am trying to remove the `locationManager` in two cases:

- When the user click the checkbox in the menu of  MainActivity.
- or when he closes the app (Not when the user changes the activity).

How can I distinguish whether onDestroy is being invoked cause the user cloeses the app or when it being called when the user switches between the activities?

I appreciate any help.

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        AsyncTaskCallback {
    TrackingService mService;
    boolean mBound = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.route_available);
        // Start the TrackingService class.
        Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
        startService(i);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        System.out.println("test onCreateOptionsMenu was invoked.");

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem checkable = menu.findItem(R.id.checkable_menu);
        checkable.setChecked(isChecked);
        return true;
    }

    // Start and stop the background service.
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.checkable_menu:
            if (isChecked = !item.isChecked()) {
                item.setChecked(isChecked);
                Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
                startService(i);
                System.out.println("test if onOptionsItemSelected");
            } else {
                mService.stopTrackingService();

            }
            return true;

        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
    stopService(i);

    }

}
```

**TrackingService class:**

```
public class TrackingService extends Service implements AsyncTaskCallback,
        LocationListener {
    LocationManager lm;
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        detectLocation();
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    private void detectLocation() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "Inside detectlocation()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30 * 1000, 0,
                this);
        enableGPS(lm);

    }
    @Override
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(wifi_receiver);
    System.out.println("ABC TrackingService onDestroy() was invoked.");

    if(lm != null){
        lm.removeUpdates(this);
        System.out.println("ABC TrackingService lm was removed.");
    }else{
        System.out.println("ABC TrackingService lm locationManager is null.");

    }       
  }
public void stopTrackingService(){
    lm.removeUpdates(this);
  }
}
```

**Map activity:**

```
public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener{
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
 // To stop the service when the user closed the app in the background and the map ativity was opened.      
        stopAlarm();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
        stopService(i);
        System.out.println("ABC Map onDestroy() was invoked!");

    }

}
```

**Edit with isFinishing:**

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(isFinishing()){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
        stopService(i);
        System.out.println("ABC Map onDestroy() was invoked!" + isFinishing());

    }


}
```

Comment: `public boolean isFinishing()`

Comment: @pskink: I have tried it but this method is being called when the user switches the app and when the app is being close in both cases return true.

Comment: what do you mean by "but this method is being called" ?

Comment: `isFinishing` is invoked in both cases and retruns true. How can I use it if I am missing something?

Comment: Please take a look at my last edit code snippet. Also I mean in both cases isFinishing is true then the service is stopped.

Comment: no, if the user presses back button `isFinishing` returns true, when user starts new activity (`startActivity`) `isFinishing` returns false, try this: http://codeshare.io/8tQhz

Comment: @pskink: I cant check isFinishing() inside the TrackingService class? I have tried it inside the MainActivity but when the service starts the onDestroy() in MainActivity is not being called. When the user clicks the button in the MainActivity which starts the service, alaramManager with IntentService is triggered to retrieve data from the server to the map activity  every 10 seconds. `onDestroyed()` in the `MainActivity` is called when the app closes the app but ´onDestroy()´ in the TrackingService is called when the `stopService(i)` is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can't distinguish that on at the `Activity` level in a general way.  For your program, you know when you are starting an another activity, so you can keep track of it yourself.

You can keep a member variable,

```
   boolean mOpeningMap = false;
```

Where ever in your code you call `startActivity`, set `mOpeningMap = true`, and change your `onDestroy` to --

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(!mOpeningMap){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);
        stopService(i);
        System.out.println("ABC Map onDestroy() was invoked!");    
    }
}
```

set the variable to false in `onResume` to make sure it is reset when you come back from the `MapActivity`.